# Convert String to Number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I think this must be really simple. I have a series of numbers which are imported as strings. I want to convert them from strings to numbers. I thought that the `.to_f` should do that but I just get the error "undefined method `/' for "1.24":String". I've included some test code below.

```
z = "1.24"
x = "3.43"
z.to_f
x.to_f
@check = z/x
```

Comment: `z.to_f` and `x.to_f` aren't doing what you think, as they don't "cast" values in place. Try `z = "1.24".to_f; x = "3.43".to_f; @check = z/x` or `@check = z.to_f/x.to_f`

Comment: Hint: You are completely ignoring the number returned by `String#to_f` and throwing it away. Don't do that.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question has been answered really well (three times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to_f` call does not change the variable itself (but returns a float, roughly speaking). You have at least following options:

**1. Assign return value of to_f to a new variable**

```
x = "3.43"
z = "1.24"

x_float = x.to_f
z_float = z.to_f

@check = z_float/x_float
```

**2. Call when the calculation is done**
(Like in @Sean s answer)

**3. Call on first assignment**

```
x = "3.43".to_f
z = "1.24".to_f

@check = z/x
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `to_f` does not reassign the value of the variable:

```
z = "1.24"
x = "3.43"
z.to_f
# ^^ z is still a string
x.to_f
# ^^ x is still a string
@check = z/x
# Perhaps z.to_f / x.to_f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it still more simple:

```
z = "1.24"
x = "3.43"
@check = Float(z)/Float(x)
```